# PQRS is a cyclic quadrilateral. If SQ bisect <PQR prove chord PS = chord SR

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image: diagram]

$PQRS$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. If $\overline{SQ}$ bisects $\angle PQR$ prove chord $\overline{PS}$ = chord $\overline{SR}$.

Comment: Sheesh, I already embedded the image for you and cleaned up your notation...

Comment: thanks, I'm inexperienced with the notation on web and as a new user I couldn't embed an image.

Comment: Here's a sketch: $\angle PQS$ and $\angle RQS$ would be congruent, and thus subtend congruent arcs. Since $\stackrel{\frown}{PS}$ and $\stackrel{\frown}{SR}$ are congruent, then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [The Inscribed Angle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) says that $\angle PQS$ is half the central angle of chord $\overline{PS}$ and $\angle SQR$ is half the central angle of chord $\overline{SR}$.  Since $\overline{SQ}$ bisects $\angle PQR$, $\angle PQS = \angle SQR$. Therefore, $\overline{PS}=\overline{SR}$ by SAS (side-angle-side).

Comment: thanks robjohn, I can't believe I overlooked that. I was trying to use a congruent triangles proof, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: out of curiosity is is possible to prove this using the triangles on the diagram?

Comment: @MrK: Without first proving a theorem that says that the length of a chord is dependent only on the diameter of the circle and the cosine of the inscribed angle subtended by the chord, I don't see a way without introducing some addition construction.